# Make buttons, selects and inputs all the same height

Tags: html, css, border-box

I'm trying to make all my form elements the same height. Normally I'd just set a height on each item and job's a good'n! But the dev's I'm working with are adamant I use padding for the buttons incase they need to wrap so the text doesn't get cut off ...by argument would be that's a problem that needs to be solved as well but anyways...

So I have this CodePen showing all my styles. I've included all the CSS just incase anything is being inherited I've missed. I've managed to get most of them the same height by using the same `font-size`, `padding` and `line-height`.

https://codepen.io/moy/pen/pVeOyQ

The problem is one of the buttons doesn't have a `border` and everything else does, so it's off by a few pixels. I thought `border-box` would solve this but obviously not!

I could add a border to that button as well and always make sure it's the same colour as the background - but that's a bit of the pain. Is it the only way though?

I know this is a bit of a minor/simple issue but I just want to get some feedback before making a decision.

I've included the CodePen as I couldn't embed all the CSS as it exceeded the limit. Also I couldn't get all the elements horizontally inline on the embed code as there wasn't enough room.

Comment: Can you make a demo that includes only the CSS relevant to your question? Thanks

Comment: There's a CodePen link. I can't embed the code on the post as there's too much CSS. I included all CSS just incase something was being inherited or a parent style was affecting the styling. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could add a border to that button as well and always make sure it's the same colour as the background - but that's a bit of the pain. Is it the only way though?

Instead of that, you could add a transparent border, as shown in the snippet below.

```css
input, select, button {
    -ms-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;

    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #1111;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #transparent-border {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }

  #no-border {
    border: none;
  }
```

```html
<p>How it looks <i>with</i> the transparent border</p>

<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Input field">

<select class="" name="">
  <option value="Select">Select field</option>
</select>

<button type="button" name="button">Button</button>

<button id="transparent-border" type="button" name="button">Button with transparent border</button>

<p>How it looks <i>without</i> the transparent border</p>

<button type="button" name="button">Border</button>

<button type="button" id="no-border" name="button">No border</button>

<p>Comparison</p>

<button type="button" id="no-border" name="button">No border</button>

<button id="transparent-border" type="button" name="button">Button with transparent border</button>
```

Comment: Doh! Not sure why I didn't think of that! So every `.btn` element would have `border: 1px solid transparent` set on it. Then the buttons with borders would just need `border-color` set.

Comment: @user1406440 You only have to give the buttons that you do not want to have a visual border the property `border: 1px solid transparent`. You can style the other ones as usual. Do keep in mind that the amount of pixels have to be the same on both to keep the size equal.

Comment: Yeah I know it'll only work if the font/padding/line-height etc is the same. Otherwise there'll be inconsistencies. The `.btn` class is my core/base button style (which doesn't need a border) so if I add `border: 1px solid transparent` to that that means I can just add the `border-color` to the one that needs it :)

Comment: the select and input are different heights.  this does not work

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a min-height for all your elements?
Combined with box-sizing: border-box;